# Variable interpolation in fb:req-choice url

Tags: facebook, fbml, invitation

For my invitation feature of my Facebook Connect app I need to be able to tell which invitation a user responds to. I have decided to rely on the Facebook UID for that. How can I include that ID in the url that Facebook generates for fb:req-choice?

```
<fb:request-form action="#{@post_url}"
                method="POST"
                invite="true"
                type="my_app"
                content="<fb:name uid='#{current_user.facebook_uid}' useyou='false' /> wants to invite you to to my_app. To join him simple click 'Accept' below.<fb:req-choice url='http://my_app.com/invitation/?fb_uid={uid}' label='Accept' />">
   <fb:multi-friend-selector
              showborder="false"
              actiontext="Invite your Facebook Friends to shop on Yumshare" />
</fb:request-form>
```

Notice the {uid} in the url attrib for fb:req-choice. This is supposed to be the uid of the user that is being invited and therefore needs to be filled in on Facebooks side. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used is not totally equivalent to the above, but close enough.

When loading the page containing the fb:req-choice form, generate a unique token, which of course has to be persisted at that point, and stick that into the acceptance url. Like so:

```
<fb:request-form action="#{@post_url}"
                method="POST"
                invite="true"
                type="my_app"
                content="<fb:name uid='#{current_user.facebook_uid}' useyou='false' /> wants to invite you to to my_app. To join him simple click 'Accept' below.<fb:req-choice url='http://my_app.com/invitation/?token=#{@token}' label='Accept' />">
   <fb:multi-friend-selector
              showborder="false"
              actiontext="Invite your Facebook Friends to shop on Yumshare" />
</fb:request-form>
```

That way you can track the invitation but only in the batch of friends that the user invited in that action.

Comment: Don't GET variables get deleted during a POST action? I faintly remember I once had to to split a registration into two steps, because of that.

Comment: Yeah, that's what is happening to me, I think